# Google Chrome Version 84.0.4147.125 Session is getting null after redirecting from Payment Gateway .Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

Web application session is getting null after redirecting from Payment Gateway site. This issue happens only in Google Chrome browser. In Mozila, IE its working fine.

We are using .net MVC.

Comment: Yes! I am getting same in webAPI Action for Version 84.0.4147.125 in chrome. It was working fine before this version. And it is also working fine in edge.

Answer (score 1):

This new concept has come to save your application by attacker. So, here is the option to allow/restrict cookie for `sameSite`.

This problem got Chrome 80 or later in 2020 and it introduces new cookie values and cookie policies. Three values can be passed into the updated SameSite attribute: `Strict`, `Lax`, or `None`. If you don't specify `SameSite` attribute in `<httpCookies>` then it will default to `SameSite=Lax`.

Now, `Lax` is good for same site. If you are using cross site or iframe(it is also consider as cross site) then you need to use `none`. And if you want to restrict your cookie then you need to use `Strict`.

Example:

1. For `http` or `https`, You need to do following steps--

```
<httpCookies domain="xyz.com" requireSSL="true" sameSite="None"  />
```

You can use some attribute for `<SessionState>`

```
<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieSameSite="None" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=serverName; Initial Catalog=databaseName;
User ID=userid;Password=pass;" timeout="55"/>
```

**For local access**, You need to do following steps--

1. Launch this URL on chrome [chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies](https://chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies)
2. You will see "SameSite by default cookies" by default it is marked as `Default`, change the state as `Disabled`
3. Click on Relaunch button into the browser.
4. Make `requireSSL="false"` (on local system)

One special case for `Iframe`. If you are using Iframe to load different application in your application. Then your session will be `null` in private(incognito) window in chrome.

I have one solution for this special case. You need to use `cookieless="true" in` ```. Only if when you are not using cookies in your application.

**For your reference:**

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/miscellaneous/chrome-behavior-affects-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/samesite-cookie-update
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/miscellaneous/chrome-behavior-affects-applications

Comment: I have checked by putting **requireSSL="true"** in web.config file but its not working.

Comment: You need to add this on live config. For local, you need to do---Launch this URL on chrome "chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies"
2) You will see "SameSite by default cookies" by default it is marked as "Default", change the state as "Disabled"
3) Relaunch the browser....

My problem has been resolved by doing this.

Comment: I have followed all above steps but issue is still exist. I am using .net framework 4.5

Comment: @Vikash Chaturvedi : does this solution work for older and new browser? or after implementing above changes it will break functionality in older browser ?